# Get initial value of Firestore document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make an addition of a grocery quantity in my react native app. The groceries are coming from firebase firestore with pre-defined prices, I want that when I increase the quantity, the total count of the cart_items should be correctly calculated. I am approaching this by adding it directly from the server.

The issue is, I need to be able to get only the initial price of a grocery, so I can add and subtract at will, instead, I am getting the updated price when I add the quantity, and that updated price is being added to the current price when I need to increase the quantity again. I hope you get what I mean.

```
const increment = async (id) => {
    const itemRef = doc(db, "cartItems", id);
    await getDoc(itemRef).then(async (snapshot) => {
      // This Line of code is supposed to capture the initial value of the price
      let price = snapshot.data().data.price;
      console.log(price);
      // This Line of code is supposed to capture the initial value of the price
      await updateDoc(itemRef, {
        quantity: snapshot.data().quantity + 1,
        data: {
          ...snapshot.data().data,
          price: snapshot.data().data.price + price,
          // I am supposed to use that initial value for this calculation
        },
      });
    });
  };
```

And here's for decreasing the quantity

```
const decrement = async (id) => {
const itemRef = doc(db, "cartItems", id);
await getDoc(itemRef).then(async (snapshot) => {
  // This Line of code is supposed to capture the initial value of the price
  let price = snapshot.data().data.price;
  console.log(price);
  // This Line of code is supposed to capture the initial value of the price
  await updateDoc(itemRef, {
    quantity:
      snapshot.data().quantity === 1 ? 1 : snapshot.data().quantity - 1,
    data: {
      ...snapshot.data().data,
      price:
        snapshot.data().data.price === price
          ? price
          : snapshot.data().data.price - price,
          // I am supposed to use that initial value for this calculation
    },
  });
});
```

};

So I just need to know if there's a way I can get only the initial value of the price and not the updated value. Please let me know if I need to clarify anything about the question. It's a really pressing issue for me right now.

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer guys.

I just had to add an initial value that remains constant and doesn't change to my database. That's what I use to make the necessary calculations on my app.

Comment: Do you have business logic required to synchronize cart products information with the server?

Reading and writing to the database is an asynchronous operation and should take milliseconds or second depending on user device network speed.

Why  you don't do that operations  on front-end level?

Comment: Yes, i get just what you mean. The reason I didn't do that on the "front-end level" is because all operations are required to come directly from the database for this particular app. I would normally take care of the logic on the front-end if it were another case.